# nginx - Create subdomain to youdomain.com/test.php?ìd=1234567

Tags: nginx, subdomain, config

my question is, how it is possible to direct a subdomain to a file with PHP GET Variables.

For example:

> test1.yourdomain.com --> yourdomain.com/test.php?id=1

Does anyone know how to do this in nginx?

Thanks!

Lg Joshua

Answer (score 0):

As an exception, you can use `if`. Note that the only thing you do in that block is issuing a `return` directive, which is a safe case for `if`.

```
if ($host ~* (?<page>\D+)(?<id>\d+)\.yourdomain\.com) {
    return 301 $scheme://yourdomain.com/$page.php?id=$id;
}
```